# Content not updating when changed through socket io request

Tags: javascript, socket.io, svelte

I'm trying to change the content of the page through a socket io request, but the variable is changing, but the content of the page is staying the same

```
<script>
  import { io } from "../src/lib/socketClient";

  var screen = "this";
  io.on("screenChange",(msg)=>{
    screen = msg.screen;
  });
</script>

<div>
  {#if screen == "this"}
    <h1>this</h1>
  {:else if screen == "that"}
    <h1>that</h1>
  {/if}
</div>
```

I already checked the socket io server and the connection, the variable is changing but the content is still staying the same

Comment: How do you know the variable is changing? This should work just fine.

Comment: I added "console.log(screen);" to line 7 and it logged "that" to the console